# Incomplete type, what does this mean?

Tags: c++

I am trying to debug my program, and I am reading values from a file called intInputFile. I was looking at my local variables and saw that it says intInputFile = incomplete type. I have tried looking it up, but no clear answers, I don't know what this means. Can anyone please explain because I think this is messing up my program.

Thanks.

```
intInputFile >> fileInt;
cout << "check" <<endl;
while(!intInputFile.eof())
{
    intNode* anotherInt;
    anotherInt = new intNode;
   if(intList==NULL)
   {
       intList = anotherInt;
       lastInt = anotherInt;
       lastInt->nextNode = NULL;
       lastInt->nextNode = new intNode;
   }
   else
   {
      lastInt = lastInt->nextNode;
      lastInt->nextNode = NULL;
      lastInt->nextNode = new intNode;
   }
   lastInt->intValue = fileInt;
   intInputFile >> fileInt;
   cout << "good" <<endl;
}
```

After first execution it correctly reads in the first integer from the file , but I noticed the incomplete type when debugging. Also, I included cout <<"good"; to see if it would run to that point and when my program executed, all it did was repeatedly display "good".

Here are the includes:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <fstream>
```

And I defined it as a regular ifstream type:

```
  int fileInt; //int read from input file
  ifstream intInputFile;
```

Comment: Code snippet will help to investigate the exact reason.

Comment: Maybe its just an *incomplete type*...

Comment: @VallabhPatade I have edited my original post.

Comment: @K-ballo I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Well, you are using it in a way that would be an error if it where an *incomplete type*, so it's probably just a debugger quirk... It's a type that it has been _declared_ but not _defined_.

Comment: @K-ballo Can't I just declare it as type ifstream? I don't think I need to define anything, right?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, its probably just a debugger quirk... try another debugger (you notably forgot to mention what is the debugger that is giving you trouble, btw, pretty important detail)

Comment: I'm using an IDE CodeBlocks, and I'm not sure which debugger honestly, but it's the one available with the compiler. How can I find out which one?

Answer (score 0):

Missed includes or multiple include or something that caused the definition of the type of `intInputFile` to not be visible at that line of code.

Comment: @AA you need to show us where you define `intInputFile` and your list of includes

Comment: I defined intInputFile in the function, do I have to define it in the main?

Comment: @AA does it give any error on the line where you define it? Something like expected a `;` before `intInputFile`? Have you tried std::ifstream?

Comment: I don't get any error when I define the file. And no I haven't tried that, but I will.

Answer (score 0):

"Incomplete type" means that the tool that gives the message (most often the compiler, but in your case the debugger) does not know exactly what the type looks like. It knows there is a type, but not which members it has or how they are laid out in memory.

If the debugger tells you this, it is pretty harmless. It will not affect the execution of the program, but it might limit your debugging options (if you need to see the members of the unknown type).

If the compiler tells you this, you have a serious problem, because then the compiler can't check if the code is actually valid. This error is typically caused by a missing `#include` line for the header that defines the type.